# How to split a string with consecutive uppercase and lowercase letters (to get the number atoms of a molecule)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to play with an algorithm where it requires me to read the number of atoms contained in an array, to which I have only began to test out the possibilities and to do so I am checking the uppercase letters and lowercase letters separately and trying to join them together afterwards, here's how I was trying:

```js
function countAtoms(molecule) {
    var element = molecule;
    var newArray = [];
    console.log('Hello World');
    for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if(element[i] == element[i].toUpperCase()){
            var uppercase = element[i]+'1';
            newArray = uppercase;
            console.log(newArray);

        }
        else{
            var lowercase = element[i];
            newArray = lowercase;
            console.log(newArray)
        }
            

    }

}
```

Now i successfully managed to console them the way I wanted.

[image]

Now the algorithm requires me to print them out exactly like this:
`Cl1Na1`, but I can't seem to join the arrays, all that happens is they turn out to be like `N1a` in one line and `C1l` in the other, please help.

Comment: What are you passing into the function? What is the definition of `molecule`?

Comment: im passing exactly like this: countAtoms('NaCl'); the definition of molecule is literal, i would say. The algorithm requires me to verify how many molecules a certain chemical element passed as argument has and return the result, and i was trying to concat them doing var res = uppercase.concat(lowercase) hence the result getting printed as described above

Comment: So, given the input of `NaCl`, what are you expecting the outcome to be?

Comment: Im trying to figure out how to join the strings, as i was saying for now i managed to identify the amount of molecules in each element in this case, which is 1 Na and 1 Cl, what i wanna do now is not only make it Na1Cl1, but i also want to reverse it to Cl1Na1

Comment: Can the input be like `H2O` and `H2SO4`?

Comment: it can and it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the string into groups that start with uppercase letters. One succinct way to do this is with a regular expression:

```js
let molecule = "NaCl"
let arr = molecule.match(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/g) // match uppercase letter followed by 0 or more lower case letters
console.log(arr)
```

From there it looks like you want to map over them and add a `1`. This will give you an array that you can then join back together with `join('')`

```js
let m = "NaCl"

function countAtoms(molecule) {
    var element = molecule.match(/([A-Z][a-z]*)/g)
    return element.map(el => el+1).join('')
}
console.log(countAtoms(m))
```

Comment: yep, it looks exactly like what i was aiming for

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle a molecule like `H2SO4`

Comment: That's not part of the question (or it wasn't when I wrote the answer) @IanMcLaird. It looks like the OP is doing this one step at a time. For all we know the "atoms contained in an array" may be like `['H', 'H', 'S', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below regex to split the items along with their atom count. This works even with molecules like `H2SO4`, `H2O` etc.

```js
const molecule = "H2SO4",
      arr = molecule.match(/[A-Z][a-z]*\d?/g),
      mappedArray = arr.map(a => /\d/g.test(a) ? a : a+1),
      joinedString = mappedArray.join('');
      
console.log(mappedArray)
console.log(joinedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

there you have, using `reduce` and then looping over and object with all the sums :)

```js
function countAtoms(molecule) {
  console.log('Hello World');
  const sums = molecule.reduce((sum, atomKey) => {
    const atom = atomKey.toUpperCase()
    if (!sum[atom]) sum[atom] = 0;
    sum[atom] += 1;
    return sum;
  }, {})

  let finalString = '';

  Object.keys(sums).forEach(sumKey => {
    finalString += sumKey + sums[sumKey];
  })

  return finalString;


}

const result = countAtoms(['NA', 'CA', 'H', 'H', 'NA', 'na']);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of making below changes to existing code

1. newArray variable to empty string, `var newArray = '';`
2. Concat everytime instead of over writing newArray variable, `newArray += uppercase;` and `newArray += lowercase;`

```js
function countAtoms(molecule) {
    var element = molecule;
    var newArray = '';
    console.log('Hello World');
    for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if(element[i] == element[i].toUpperCase()){
            var uppercase = element[i]+'1';
            newArray += uppercase;
            console.log(newArray);

        }
        else{
            var lowercase = element[i];
            newArray += lowercase;
            console.log(newArray)
        }
            

    }

}

countAtoms('NaCl')
```